# Why did Starship perform an abrupt course correction seconds before stage separation?

Tags: spacex-starship, launch-trajectories, spacex-super-heavy

During Starship second integrated test flight [IFT-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Starship_Second_Integrated_Flight_Test)
There is a seemingly rapid attitude change seconds before stage separation, the whole vehicle making a turn towards the right of the image.

What is the reason for this sharp turn?

The course correction is visible in [this video](https://youtu.be/hF2C7xE9Mj4?si=Rv-Rus8fpJQ0Gwiq&t=67), occuring roughly between T+02:22 and T+02:33

Comment: could be a thrust imbalance during booster throttle-down? interesting question.

Comment: Could be they want to use the 13 gimbaling engines with the longer lever arm on the booster to tighten the gravity turn as opposed to the 3 gimbaling engines on the ship.

Comment: Rockets typically don't fly at zero angle of attack. I suspect they were zeroing that out before doing the separation.